# How to combine the data from 2 left joins without UNION

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to combine the results of adr.line1 and adr1.line1 without using union as my query is very large already .
 In the example below , all the addresses of person are stored in address table through personaddress table, except the mainaddress which is FK of address.id

```
 SELECT
    adr.line1,
    adr1.line1
FROM
    person p
    LEFT JOIN personaddress pa ON p.id = pa.personid
    LEFT JOIN address adr ON adr.id = pa.addressid
    LEFT JOIN address adr1 ON p.mainaddress = adr1.id

---------------------
person 
---------------------
|   id  |   name   |    mainaddress |   
|   1   |   steve  |    null        |   
|   2   |   john   |    3           |   

---------------------
personaddress 
----------------------
|   id   |  personid |  addressid   |    
|   1    |  1        |  2           |   

---------------------
address
----------------------
|   id  |   addressline1    |   
|   1   |   1 main st       |   
|   2   |   10 city st      |   
|   3   |   100 wide rd     |   

---------------------
Query result is -
--------------------
|   adr.line1     | adr1.line1  |   
|   10 city st    | 100 wide rd |
```

---

```
What I am looking for -
--------------------
|   adr.line1     |     
|   10 city st    |
|   100 wide rd   |
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What do you mean by 'combine' - get a single column with separate rows for the values form the two tables? Can you extract the bulk of your query to a CTE and then base a union on that? Or can you unpivot the results you get now?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a union either way, use a subquery union within your SQL like

```
 SELECT
    SUB.line1
FROM
    person p
    LEFT JOIN personaddress pa ON p.id = pa.personid
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT id, line1
        FROM address adr ON adr.id = pa.addressid

        UNION

        SELECT mainaddress AS Id, line1
        FROM address adr1 ) SUB ON SUB.Id = pa.addressid
```

Answer (score 0):

if i didn't misunderstand , coalesce funtion  works for this.

```sql
SELECT
    coalesce(adr.line1,
    adr1.line1) adr
FROM
    person p
    LEFT JOIN personaddress pa ON p.id = pa.personid
    LEFT JOIN address adr ON adr.id = pa.addressid
    LEFT JOIN address adr1 ON p.mainaddress = adr1.id
```